# VS Code Python extension prompts me to select an interpreter when one is selected

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my Django application, but VS Code's Python extension prompts me to select an interpreter any time I hit run, even after I've selected the Python executable in my virtual environment.

[image: Alert and status bar]

*launch.json*

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Django",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
      "args": ["runserver", "localhost:9000", "--noreload"],
      "django": true,
      "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

What can I do to make this pesky alert go away so I can start debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, what you marked was debug option, interpreter should be the one on the left:

[image]

You can choose the existed python environment by the **Python: Select Interpreter** command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P);

OR create a virtual environment by running the command `python -m venv <name>` in Terminal. When you create a new virtual environment, a prompt will be displayed to allow you to select it for the workspace. Select YES:

[image]

More detailed information, you can refer to [Python Environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) and [Django Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django).